# MsBuild condition count items

Tags: msbuild

I want error to be thrown if number of data-items more than one.
Why doesn't the following work? How do I code correct expression?

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Data Include="a"/>
  <Data Include="b"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Error Text="Error!" Condition="@(Data->Count()) &gt; 1" />
```

ps. msbuild v4.0

Answer (score 35):

I've found solution: You want to wrap your expression with the single quotes

```
<Error Text="Error!" Condition="'@(Data->Count())' &gt; 1" />
```

Comment: single brackets or single quotes? :) Accept your answer as well.

Comment: Not sure when they fixed this, but, as of Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework, the op's original code works - it seems no single quotes or brackets needed.